# How can i change this function to only give me the project folder path on express?(__dirpath)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/404.html');
});
```

The current fucntion is giving me this path ...\Ex1\server\views\404.html how can i change the function to give me this path  Ex1\views\404.html and send the html file.

[image]

Comment: __dirname will give the directory name of the file the code is in. So you might use something like ‘../views/‘ instead of ‘/views/‘. However you should take a look the the path.resolve function. This will build a correct path for you (multi os compatible).

Comment: i try to use ../views/ didnt work so i use path.normalize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  const path = require('path');
  const fpath = path.normalize(__dirname + "/..");
  res.sendFile(fpath + '/views/404.html');
});
```

To resolve my problem i had to get the "path" module https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html and use the path.normalize method.

path.normalize(__dirname + "/..");

where 
__dirname  is   "\Ex1\server"

Using __dirname + "/.." in path.normalize it will return only the Ex1 then i added 
 "/views/404.html" to return the file i pretended.